# array traversal algorithm to load the array with Rationals

Tags: java, arrays, object, traversal

I have a java class already made up of methods and am in the process of creating a driver java class and just need some help figuring out how to load my traversal array with rationals. I have the following but I need help figuring out how to load it with the rationals.

```
    public static void main(String [] args)
       {
       //Creates the array
          Rational[] rats = new Rational[6];
          for(int i=0; i < rats.length; i++)
          { 
             rats[i] = new Rational(2,18); //this will call constructor. 
             //{4/5, 4/19, 3/8, 9/3, 2/4, 24/7 }; I want to load these into the array instead of
             // just 2,8 (2/8) (numerator, denominator)

          }
```

I have two constructors, an EVC and DVC named public Rational() and public Rational(int num,int den)
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the array doing

```
Rational[] rationals = new Rational[] { new Rational(2, 18), new Rational(4, 5), ... };
```

(Sorry I couldn't name the array rats lol).

EDIT:

If you're going to load the numbers from a file, you can do something like

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
int currentRational = 0;
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
  int num = scanner.nextInt();
  int den = scanner.nextInt();
  scanner.nextLine();
  rationals[currentRational] = new Rational(num, den);
  currentRational++; 
}
```

This is assuming your file has this format

```
10 3
4 5
etc.
```

Comment: lol thanks xp500, could I load the values in the array using an array traversal? if so how?

Comment: You could if there was a pattern in the rationals you're adding (which I don't see). You can also load those rationals from a file in which case you would read the file and add them to the array as you read them. In this last case you are also avoiding having those rationals hardcoded.

Comment: Nice, I like the file ideal, I will try that.

Comment: how would I add them to the file?  File myFile = new File("rationals.txt"); 
      Scanner in = new Scanner(myFile); 
      Rational[] rationals = in.nextInt(); 
      in.nextLine(); 
would I add them to the file as,
2,18
3,5

Comment: I mean you write a file with whatever format you like (e.g 1 rational per line), and then you parse the file and load the rationals into the array

Comment: ok been working on it for hours, I created the file but how do I load the file into the array? thanks so much